# What is the Mach Never Exceed number for a C-130J Hercules under ISA conditions (approximations are welcomed!)

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, military, c-130

I am looking for the Mach Never Exceed number for a C-130J Hercules so that I can create an approximate 1g envelope.
Does anyone have any idea what this can be? I am trying to find the value for similar aircrafts so that I can make an educated approximation but I am having no such luck. Perhaps someone with more experience can provide me with an educated estimation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *M<sub>MO</sub>* for a C-130J is **Mach 0.77** according to [flugzeuginfo.net](http://www.flugzeuginfo.net/acdata_php/acdata_c130_en.php). Official values will be found in the AFM for the aircraft and may vary between production variants of the C-130.

Comment: Thank you so much!